# How to implement scala function to provide the forEach function of Apache Spark Dataframe RDD?

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have created a DataFrame RDD using the following code

```
_DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", options);_  
_jdbcDF = jdbcDF.cache();_
```

I need to apply custom search logic on the RDD to find records that match a certain criteria. This is something that the existing filter function may not be able to provide. Is there a way I can pass a custom java function to the DataFrame filter() function such that it returns the list of matching records. Something like one listed below

```
_DataFrame tableRows = jdbcDF.filter( customJavaFunction() );_
```

Comment: You'll have to create your own filter function. If you want us to help you, you'll need to provide more information about your filter or a pseudo code in case you are having trouble writing the code for it

Comment: My problem is that the filter function of DataFrame does not accept a function. The JavaRDD<String> can accept a function as listed below _javaRdd.filter( customFunction )_ . I am looking for a similar functionality for the DataFrame RDD. I realised that DataFrame RDD can accept a function as a argument for its functions like forEach which is fine. I need some help in writing a sample function in java that gets called by the DataFrame.forEach( _customFunction_)

Comment: the dataframe filter accepts conditions in a string. what more do you need for the filter?

Comment: you have to be more specific about the function you need to write.